# Allow to send mail from domain with SPF record

Tags: google-apps, spf

I have question concerning SPF records.

The website (eg www.example.com) of one of my clients has a contact form that sends mails to contact@example.com.

We only provide the hosting of the website so we do not manage email accounts, DNS records, etc .. only webspace. So my clients manages the DNS settings, nameservers, mail servers, etc..

The mails are sent using PHP but they are never received by contact@example.com
When I change contact@example.com to an email address outside the domein eg contact@test.com, I do receive the contact email.

My conclusion is that their mailserver blocks mails from our IP address because PHP sends mails to an email address that has the same domain but has another IP.

Also, my client uses Google Apps for email so the MX records on their DNS server point to Google.

How can I fix this issue? Does my client need to add an SPF record that accepts our IP address? If so, whats the correct SPF syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your the domain has SPF records defined then you need to add the address of the web server to the SPF records.
You can check the SPF records of the domain on this website: http://spf.myisp.ch

The best way would be to check the log files on the web server or on the server of the receiver to find out what the problem is.

Comment: FYI http://spf.myisp.ch is not provide spf infos anymore.

Comment: Thx. It should soon work again. Alternatively, you can go to http://spf.marketvision.ch.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure cpanel does not have any MX records since you are not hosting the dns